# Can we route using plated through hole in a Multilayer PCB?

Tags: pcb-design, pcb-fabrication, pcb-layers

Hi I'm designing a 4 Layer PCB for my project this is my first time using a ML4 Board. Layer Configuation are as follows.
-L1 [red]
-L2 (GND)[purple]
-L3 [light blue]
-L4 [dark blue]

My question is I have a through hole via or plated through hole running from L1 to L4 can terminate signals running on L3 on to that L1 to L4 (through hole via or plated through hole)

[image: illustration]

Comment: look at the stack up of the through hole.

Comment: Yes, vias are how you connect between different layers, and yes, a through via can connect to any of the layers between the top and bottom layers. Read [What are the rules to make different drill pairs for VIAs in PCB layers?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/325951/what-are-the-rules-to-make-different-drill-pairs-for-vias-in-pcb-layers).

Comment: Yes. A plated through hole is kind of like a big via.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you mean "is it ok to use a through-hole that's part of a footprint as a via"? Yes it's totally legit to do that. They're made in exactly the same way, the only difference is that vias will usually often have solder mask left over them.